Redirect requests to a Web Application to a different Web Application on the same IIS server
I have an IIS Server. When a new application is launched, I update the application link on the organization's portal-site. However, many users have saved bookmarks for the old application. We still use the old application on the server side for certain features, but we don't want it to be directly accessible to the organization.
I need to set up a redirect for other users so that when they try to access HRapp, they are redirected to NewHRapp.


Likely you might write a complex URL rewrite rule, but you need to learn more about how to distinguish those users from yourself if you don’t want to redirect yourself.

Do they connenct on DNS or on IP?
If on DNS you can just add the binding to the new site.
If the site is not on the same iis you can use HTTP Redirection (i think you already have it installed if not you need to add it using the server manager.)

We utilized the same web site, and IIS Server. I've one web site and some application...I require the previous HRapp, but users accessed it from their bookmarks or browser history. I am unable to alter the application's name
